# Django pages loading very slowly in EC2

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm at a loss here.

I am attempting to transfer a Django application to EC2. I ave moved the DB to RDS(Postgres image) and have static and media on S3.

However for some reason, all my pages are taking 25-30 seconds to load. I have checked the images and CPU and memory barely blips. I checked and took off KeepAlive in Apache, and changed the WSGI to work in daemon mode, but none of this made any difference. I have gone into the shell on the machine and accessed the DB and that appears to be reacting fine as well. I ahve also increased the EC2 image, with no effect.

S3 items are also being delivered quickly and without issue. Only the rendering of the html is taking long times.

On our current live and test server, there are no issues with the pages which load in ms

Can anyone point me to where or what I should be looking at?

Marc

Comment: Just to add, I changed the template to load just 'Hello World' and I got the same

Comment: Further tests show that a request.is_authenticated() was taking 11 seconds and the render of a simple 'Hello world' page was taking 14. It also appeared that the time taken is always near 25 seconds. I have the same code running on a test server and our live one and the same page takes ms.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appeared to be connected with using RDS. I installed Postgres on the EC2 image and appart from a little mucking around it worked fine on there.

I'm going to try building a new RDS, but that was the issue here. Strange it worked ok directly via manage.py shell